# Find all sequences with the same column value

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
╔══════╦═════════╗
║ Code ║ Airline ║
╠══════╬═════════╣
║    1 ║ AF      ║
║    1 ║ KL      ║
║    8 ║ AR      ║
║    8 ║ AZ      ║
║    8 ║ DL      ║
╚══════╩═════════╝

dat <- structure(list(Code = c(1L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 8L), Airline = structure(c(1L, 
5L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("AF  ", "AR  ", "AZ  ", "DL", "KL  "
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Code", "Airline"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

My goal is for each airline to find all shared codes, i.e. the codes used by one or more other airlines.
So the output would be

```
+--------------------+
| Airline SharedWith |
+--------------------+
| AF      "KL"       |
| KL      "AF"       |
| AR      "AZ","DL"  |
+--------------------+
```

the pseudocode is any imperative language would be

```
for each code
  lookup all rows in the table where the value = code
```

Since R is not that much list oriented, what would be the best way to achieve the expected output?

Comment: It is better to provide sample input in a form that can be fed to R. Makes it easier for people who want to help you.

Comment: Use `dput` to output the data into a form that can easily be imported

Comment: added a sample from CSV

Comment: Not that much list oriented?  Lol, it's only the main data structure in R.

Comment: This is not the point of the question, but I would say data frames are the main data structures in R.

Comment: So would I.  We can agree on that.

Comment: Actually...the data frame is a list :)

Answer (score 10):

Several options using the `data.table` package:

**1)** Using `strsplit`, `paste` & operate by row:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, Airline := trimws(Airline)  # this step is needed to remove the leading and trailing whitespaces
           ][, sharedwith := paste(Airline, collapse = ','), Code
            ][, sharedwith := paste(unlist(strsplit(sharedwith,','))[!unlist(strsplit(sharedwith,',')) %in% Airline], 
                                    collapse = ','), 1:nrow(dat)]
```

which gives:

```
> dat
   Code Airline sharedwith
1:    1      AF         KL
2:    1      KL         AF
3:    8      AR      AZ,DL
4:    8      AZ      AR,DL
5:    8      DL      AR,AZ
```

**2)** Using `strsplit` & `paste` with `mapply` instead of `by = 1:nrow(dat)`:

```
setDT(dat)[, Airline := trimws(Airline)
           ][, sharedwith := paste(Airline, collapse = ','), Code
             ][, sharedwith := mapply(function(s,a) paste(unlist(strsplit(s,','))[!unlist(strsplit(s,',')) %in% a], 
                                                          collapse = ','),
                                      sharedwith, Airline)][]
```

which will give you the same result.

**3)** Or by using the `CJ` function with `paste` (inspired by the `expand.grid` solution of @zx8754):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, Airline := trimws(Airline)
           ][, CJ(air=Airline, Airline,  unique=TRUE)[air!=V2][, .(shared=paste(V2,collapse=',')), air],
             Code]
```

which gives:

```
   Code air shared
1:    1  AF     KL
2:    1  KL     AF
3:    8  AR  AZ,DL
4:    8  AZ  AR,DL
5:    8  DL  AR,AZ
```

---

A solution with `dplyr` & `tidyr` to get the desired solution (inspired by @jaimedash):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat <- dat %>% mutate(Airline = trimws(as.character(Airline)))

dat %>%
  mutate(SharedWith = Airline) %>% 
  group_by(Code) %>%
  nest(-Code, -Airline, .key = SharedWith) %>%
  left_join(dat, ., by = 'Code') %>%
  unnest() %>%
  filter(Airline != SharedWith) %>%
  group_by(Code, Airline) %>%
  summarise(SharedWith = toString(SharedWith))
```

which gives:

```
   Code Airline SharedWith
  (int)   (chr)      (chr)
1     1      AF         KL
2     1      KL         AF
3     8      AR     AZ, DL
4     8      AZ     AR, DL
5     8      DL     AR, AZ
```

Answer (score 9):

An an `igraph` approach

```
library(igraph)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(dat)

# Find neighbours for select nodes
ne <- setNames(ego(g,2, nodes=as.character(dat$Airline), mindist=2), dat$Airline)
ne
#$`AF  `
#+ 1/7 vertex, named:
#[1] KL  

#$`KL  `
#+ 1/7 vertex, named:
#[1] AF  
---
---

# Get final format
data.frame(Airline=names(ne), 
           Shared=sapply(ne, function(x)
                                      paste(V(g)$name[x], collapse=",")))
#   Airline Shared
# 1      AF     KL
# 2      KL     AF
# 3      AR  AZ,DL
# 4      AZ  AR,DL
# 5      DL  AR,AZ
```

Answer (score 8):

I think all you would need is a `table`

```
dat <- structure(list(Code = c(1L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 8L),Airline = structure(c(1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L),.Label = c("AF", "AR", "AZ", "DL", "KL"),class = "factor")),.Names = c("Code", "Airline"),class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

tbl <- crossprod(table(dat))
diag(tbl) <- 0

#        Airline
# Airline AF AR AZ DL KL
#      AF  0  0  0  0  1
#      AR  0  0  1  1  0
#      AZ  0  1  0  1  0
#      DL  0  1  1  0  0
#      KL  1  0  0  0  0

dd <- data.frame(Airline = colnames(tbl),
                 shared = apply(tbl, 1, function(x)
                   paste(names(x)[x > 0], collapse = ', ')))

merge(dat, dd)
#   Airline Code shared
# 1      AF    1     KL
# 2      AR    8 AZ, DL
# 3      AZ    8 AR, DL
# 4      DL    8 AR, AZ
# 5      KL    1     AF
```

Comment: all hail `table`. very nice use of it

Answer (score 6):

There is likely a more efficient route, but this should fly:

```
# example data
d <- data.frame(code = c(1,1,8,8,8),
     airline = c("AF","KL","AR","AZ","DL"),
     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# merge d to itself on the code column.  This isn't necessarily efficient
d2 <- merge(d, d, by = "code")

# prune d2 to remove occasions where
# airline.x and airline.y (from the merge) are equal
d2 <- d2[d2[["airline.x"]] != d2[["airline.y"]], ]
# construct the combinations for each airline using a split, apply, combine
# then, use stack to get a nice structure for merging
d2 <- stack(
      lapply(split(d2, d2[["airline.x"]]),
        function(ii) paste0(ii$airline.y, collapse = ",")))

# merge d and d2.  "ind" is a column produced by stack
merge(d, d2, by.x = "airline", by.y = "ind")
#  airline code values
#1      AF    1     KL
#2      AR    8  AZ,DL
#3      AZ    8  AR,DL
#4      DL    8  AR,AZ
#5      KL    1     AF
```

Comment: "but this should fly" - Nice pun.

Answer (score 5):

Using expand.grid and aggregate:

```
do.call(rbind,
        lapply(split(dat, dat$Code), function(i){
          x <- expand.grid(i$Airline, i$Airline)
          x <- x[ x$Var1 != x$Var2, ]
          x <- aggregate(x$Var2, list(x$Var1), paste, collapse = ",")
          colnames(x) <- c("Airline", "SharedWith")
          cbind(Code = i$Code, x)
        }))

# output
#     Code Airline SharedWith
# 1.1    1      AF         KL
# 1.2    1      KL         AF
# 8.1    8      AR      AZ,DL
# 8.2    8      AZ      AR,DL
# 8.3    8      DL      AR,AZ
```

Answer (score 4):

`split` helps. Here's a fully reproducible EDIT that works w/o any additional package. Works with the OPs data.frame - changed it after OP added a reproducible dataset.

```
# strip white space in Airline names:
dat$Airline <- gsub(" ","",dat$Airline)
li <- split(dat,factor(dat$Code))
do.call("rbind",lapply(li,function(x) 
data.frame(Airline = x[1,2],
         SharedWith = paste(x$Airline[-1]
                            ,collapse=",")
))
)
```

Comment: I managed to achive similar by group_by from dplyr. But then I am stuck in finding all permutations per column.

Comment: Try: `df %>% group_by(code) %>% mutate(SharedWith = paste(sort(Airline), collapse = ', '))` This retains airline in the same column too.

Comment: Great! This is much better! But I need to exclude the same airline, because now it is also shared with itself.

Comment: @AndreiVaranovich a `dplyr` free solution with base R, that should give exactly the output you specified above... However – I don't know what you are really trying to do in the end. but I have a hunch, the approach is a bit unRish.

Comment: @AndreiVaranovich does this fix the repeat issue? The advantage of this solution is that you don't need another package. That being said, I like @Procrastinatus Maximus because `data.table` is really cool and likely the fastest solution in terms of computing time.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(code) %>% mutate(SharedWith = paste(sort(Airline), collapse = ', ')) %>% ungroup() %>% select(Airline, SharedWith)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the following as a comment that is posted as an answer just because this allows more convenient formatting.

```
for each code
  lookup all rows in the table where the value = code
```

ummm... sorry, I don't get how this psedudocode is related to your desired output

```
+--------------------+
| Airline SharedWith |
+--------------------+
| AF      "KL"       |
| KL      "AF"       |
| AR      "AZ","DL"  |
+--------------------+
```

The result of this pseudocode should rather be:

```
+---------------------+
+ Code  +  Airlines   +
+---------------------+
+  1    +  AF, KL     +
+  2    +  AR, AZ, DL +
+---------------------+
```

That is,

```
codes <- unique(dat$Code)
data.frame(Code=codes, Airlines = sapply(codes, function(x) paste(subset(dat, Code %in% x)$Airline, collapse=",")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quickly with `tidyr`'s `nest` (although unless you first translate Airline as factor to character it's less quick) and `merge`

```
 library(tidyr)
 dat$Airline <- as.character(dat$Airline)
 new_dat <- merge(dat, dat %>% nest(-Code, .key= SharedWith), by="Code")
```

and

```
> new_dat
  Code Airline SharedWith
1    1      AF     AF, KL
2    1      KL     AF, KL
3    8      AR AR, AZ, DL
4    8      AZ AR, AZ, DL
5    8      DL AR, AZ, DL
```

*an advantage* of this solution over some of the others: `SharedWith` becomes a list-column of `data.frame` rather than say a character

```
> str(new_dat$SharedWith)
List of 5
 $ :'data.frame':   2 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ Airline: chr [1:2] "AF" "KL"
 $ :'data.frame':   2 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ Airline: chr [1:2] "AF" "KL"
 $ :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ Airline: chr [1:3] "AR" "AZ" "DL"
 $ :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ Airline: chr [1:3] "AR" "AZ" "DL"
 $ :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ Airline: chr [1:3] "AR" "AZ" "DL"
```

so you can then easily (albiet not prettily) index out vectors of the shared values, like:

```
> new_dat$SharedWith[[1]]$Airline
[1] "AF" "KL"
```

rather than having to use `strsplit` or similar