# Speed up pairwise counting of unique observations

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

I have a vector of objects (`object`) along with a corresponding vector of time frames (`tframe`) in which the objects were observed.  For each unique pair of objects, I want to calculate *the number of time frames in which both objects were observed*.

I can write the code using `for()` loops, but it takes a long time to run as the number of unique objects increases.  How might I change the code to speed up the run time?

Below is an example with 4 unique objects (in reality I have about 300).  For example, objects `a` and `c` were both observed in time frames `1` and `2`, so they get a count of `2`.  Objects `b` and `d` were never observed in the same time frame, so they get a count of `0`.

```
object <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d")
tframe <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1)

uo <- unique(object)
n <- length(uo)

mpairs <- matrix(NA, nrow=n*(n-1)/2, ncol=3, dimnames=list(NULL, 
  c("obj1", "obj2", "sametf")))

row <- 0
for(i in 1:(n-1)) {
for(j in (i+1):n) {
  row <- row+1
  mpairs[row, "obj1"] <- uo[i]
  mpairs[row, "obj2"] <- uo[j]
  # no. of time frames in which both objects in a pair were observed
  intwin <- intersect(tframe[object==uo[i]], tframe[object==uo[j]])
  mpairs[row, "sametf"] <- length(intwin)
}}

data.frame(object, tframe)
   object tframe
1       a      1
2       a      1
3       a      2
4       b      2
5       b      3
6       c      1
7       c      2
8       c      2
9       c      3
10      d      1

mpairs
     obj1 obj2 sametf
[1,] "a"  "b"  "1"   
[2,] "a"  "c"  "2"   
[3,] "a"  "d"  "1"   
[4,] "b"  "c"  "2"   
[5,] "b"  "d"  "0"   
[6,] "c"  "d"  "1"
```

Comment: Dont know if it will be faster, but arguably  clearer ... `tab <- tcrossprod(table(unique(d)))` gets you the counts you want, so then rearrange (if needed) `tab[lower.tri(tab, TRUE)] <- NA ; reshape2::melt(tab, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: similar [Find all sequences with the same column value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36827378/find-all-sequences-with-the-same-column-value)

Comment: @user20650 What is `d` in your example?

Comment: ah, sorry. `d <- data.frame(object, tframe)`

Comment: @user20650  That works.  Short, clear, and FAST.  I used a modification ... `crossprod(table(tframe, object)>0)`.

Comment: @user20650 If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `crossproduct` to get the counts of agreement. You can then reshape the 
data, if required.

Example

```
object <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d")
tframe <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1)

# This will give you the counts
# Use code from Jean's comment
tab <- tcrossprod(table(object, tframe)>0)

# Reshape the data
tab[lower.tri(tab, TRUE)] <- NA 
reshape2::melt(tab, na.rm=TRUE)
```